# pre-populate iron-menu with custom data

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

is there a way to pre-populate the iron-menu element with data instead of creating a new custom element, or can it be extended? using polymer 1.0.
    I had created my own element and satisfied the above requirements but is it really sane to create an element that's almost the exact copy of an existing one? consider this:

Here is iron-menu element code:

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/iron-menu-behavior/iron-menubar-behavior.html">

<dom-module id="system-menu">

  <style>

    .content ::content > .iron-selected {
      color: red;
    }

    .content ::content > * {
      display: inline-block;
    }

  </style>

  <template>

    <div class="content">
      <content></content>
    </div>

  </template>

</dom-module>

<script>

(function() {

  Polymer({

    is: 'system-menu',

    behaviors: [
      Polymer.IronMenubarBehavior
    ]

  });

})();

</script>
```

**I want to preserve the iron-menu behaviour.** When using it, cant I do something like this:

```
<system-menu class="list">
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{data}">
        <li>{{item.label}}</li>
    </template>
</system-menu>
```

This code I took from the iron-menu-behaviour example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this, looks like I wasnt escaping `{{data}}` My array was something like this

```
[{"label":"login","url":"\/login","parent_id":"0"},{"label":"register","url":"\/register","parent_id":"0"}]
```

And I was sending it using `items="{{data}}"`, thus the end result would be:

```
items="{{[{"label":"login","url":"\/login","parent_id":"0"},{"label":"register","url":"\/register","parent_id":"0"}]
}}"
```

The array was php generated so I wasnt aware of the `""` quotes. I found that changing items to `items={{data}}` solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

There's no `iron-menu` element really, there's the `IronMenuBehavior` but it doesn't actually include any template, just the menu logic. That element that've you created looks find and is equivalent to `paper-menu` but with different styling.

The menu content you can either hardcode in just regular HTML or handle it iteratively, as you suggested, in some other element. There's no way to bind it imperatively that I'm aware of, so you will need to write another element (or bind it will Angular, though I've never tried that so I'm not sure if that will work) that binds to `data`.

```
<dom-module is="iron-menu">
    <template>
        <system-menu class="list">
            <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{data}}">
                <li>{{item.label}}</li>
            </template>
        </system-menu>
    </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
Polymer({
    is: "iron-menu",
    properties: {
        data: {
            type: Array,
            value: function() {
                return [
                    {label: 'Item 1'},
                    {label: 'Item 2'},
                    {label: 'Item 3'}
                ]
            }
        }
    }
})
</script>
```

One thing though, you seem to have a typo `{data}` not `{{data}}`.